# Grab UserID on login

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-state

Trying to save the `$_SESSION['uID']` within the session to use for functions like pulling up recent orders, etc.

*I have a few files:*

** login/index.php ** - This is the page users visit to login (aka enter in user/pass), which includes a bunch of html markup and this php:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');
?>
```

**check_buyer.php** - that is called when a user visits login/index.php and enters in credentials. This file, upon entering in correct credentials will store `$_SESSION` variables using the function: `validateUser{}`

```
  <?php
session_start(); #recall session from index.php where user logged include()

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        header( 'Location: buyer/' ); # return true if sessions are made and login creds are valid
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";  
    return true;
}

require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');

$connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Can't Connect to Database.");
mysql_select_db($db);

$LoginUserName = $_POST['userName'];
$LoginPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
//connect to the database here
$LoginUserName = mysql_real_escape_string($LoginUserName);
$query = "SELECT uID, uUPass, dynamSalt, uUserType FROM User WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such USER exists
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}
$ifUserExists = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

function validateUser() {
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'];
    $_SESSION['uUserType'] = 1; // 1 for buyer - 2 for merchant
}

$dynamSalt = $ifUserExists['dynamSalt'];  #get value of dynamSalt in query above
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$LoginPassword); #recreate originally created dynamic, unique pass

if($SaltyPass != $ifUserExists['uUPass']) # incorrect PASS
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}

else {
validateUser();
}
// If User *has not* logged in yet, keep on /login
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

If all login details are fine, it redirects to **/login/buyer/index.php**

```
 <?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['uUserType'] != 1) // error
{ 

    die("
    <div class='container_infinity'>
        <div class='container_full' style='position:static;'>
        <img src='img/error/noAccess.png' style='float:left;' /> <br />
        <h2>403 Error: You may not view this page. Access denied.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    ");
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    return ($_SESSION['valid'] == 1 && $_SESSION['uUserType'] == 1);
}

//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    die();
}
?>

<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1 && $_SESSION['uUserType'] == 1){
        #echo "<a href='../logout.php'>Logout</a>";
        echo 'buyerid: '.$_SESSION['uID'];
        require_once('buyer_profile.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "<a href='../index.php'>Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

When it reaches the `/login/buyer/index.php`, right now I'm JUST trying to output the user's userid aka `$buyerUserID;` as created back in the file `check_buyer.php` . Why isn't this getting any value? All pages have the `session_start();` at top too

Comment: full path of your check_buyer.php? sometimes the cookie might stored in the sublevel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `$_SESSION['uID'] = $ifUserExists['uID'];` in your login process.

EDIT:

Then in your buyer php script you need to output `$_SESSION['uID']` instead of `$buyerUserId`

```
<?php
session_start(); #recall session from index.php where user logged include()

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        header( 'Location: buyer/' ); # return true if sessions are made and login creds are valid
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";  
    return true;
}

require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');

$connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Can't Connect to Database.");
mysql_select_db($db);

$LoginUserName = $_POST['userName'];
$LoginPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
//connect to the database here
$LoginUserName = mysql_real_escape_string($LoginUserName);
$query = "SELECT uID, uUPass, dynamSalt, uUserType FROM User WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such USER exists
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}
$ifUserExists = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

function validateUser() {
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'] = (isset($ifUserExists['uID'])) ? $ifUserExists['uID'] : null;
    $_SESSION['uUserType'] = 1; // 1 for buyer - 2 for merchant
}

$dynamSalt = $ifUserExists['dynamSalt'];  #get value of dynamSalt in query above
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$LoginPassword); #recreate originally created dynamic, unique pass

if($SaltyPass != $ifUserExists['uUPass']) # incorrect PASS
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}

else {
validateUser();
}
// If User *has not* logged in yet, keep on /login
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
?>


<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['uUserType']!=1) // error
{ 

    die("
    <div class='container_infinity'>
        <div class='container_full' style='position:static;'>
        <img src='img/error/noAccess.png' style='float:left;' /> <br />
        <h2>403 Error: You may not view this page. Access denied.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    ");
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    return ($_SESSION['valid'] = 1 && $_SESSION['uUserType'] = 1);
}

//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    die();
}
?>

<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1 && $_SESSION['uUserType'] == 1){
        #echo "<a href='../logout.php'>Logout</a>";
        echo 'buyerid: '.$_SESSION['uID'];
        require_once('buyer_profile.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "<a href='../index.php'>Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where does $_SESSION['uID'] = $ifUserExists['uID']; need to be used?

Comment: Should I just get rid of the $buyerUserID = $_SESSION['uID']; and make it $_SESSION['uID']; instead?

Comment: @YoBro Yes. You setting the session to a variable is pointless as that variable gets destroyed at the end and never carries over to the next page. I would add that into `validateUser()`

Comment: Where does $_SESSION['uID'] = $ifUserExists['uID']; need to be?

Comment: $_SESSION['uID']; is sitting in validateUser()

Comment: @YoBro check the edits. I'm not a big fan of the code you have but the edits I added should work.

Comment: Jostster - this didnt do anything different. Please see all of my updated code above. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Jostster - where would you try to improve this login system if possible? Im considering re-writing it.

Comment: @YoBro You are doing it wrong. in validateUser() you need `$_SESSION['uID'] = (isset($ifUserExists['uID'])) ? $ifUserExists['uID'] : null;` instead of just `$_SESSION['uID'];`. As for the rewrite I am more of an OOP person.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    return ($_SESSION['valid'] = 1 && $_SESSION['uUserType'] = 1);
}
```

in `buyer/index.php` always returns TRUE. Did you mean:

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    return ($_SESSION['valid'] == 1 && $_SESSION['uUserType'] == 1);
}
```

Also:

```
<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1 && $_SESSION['uUserType'] = 1){
```

Might be

```
<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1 && $_SESSION['uUserType'] == 1){
```

You should pay more attention to check for equality ( == ) and assignment ( = )

Comment: I should also change `$_SESSION['uUserType']! =1` to `$_SESSION['uUserType']! ==1` right ?

Comment: No :) That's fine, unless you want to do a strict equality (checking var type also); otherwise, != is the negative of ==

Comment: Please see updated code. This still isn't capturing the uID value

Answer (score 1):

You do not set $_SESSION['uID'] anywhere in check_buyer.php

Also, note that isLoggedIn() always returns true and that calls to `header` won't make your code stop, so even if you are logged in, isLoggedIn() will continue and the user will eventually get redirected to index.php

Comment: Not to mention in /login/buyer/index.php the variable `$buyerUserID` hasn't been defined after `session_start`

Comment: Emil & Ryan - $buyerUserID is defined in the function validateUser() within check_buyer.php as $buyerUserID = $_SESSION['uID']; , I cannot just reuse this variable now in /login/buyer/index.php ?